# How to get the backgroundImage for a view with backgroundColor set using init:patternImage

Tags: ios, swift

If I set a background to my view like this:

```
let image:UIImage = UIImage(named: self.backgroundImages[self.backgroundImageIndex!])
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage:image)
```

How can i read the UIImage of the background in another place?

```
let image:UIImage = self.view.backgroundColor as UIImage  // Error
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no readily available property you can use for this. You can create your own function or add a computed property to `UIView` with an extension:

```
extension UIView {
    var backgroundImage: UIImage! {
        let rect = self.frame
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, self.backgroundColor.CGColor)
        CGContextFillRect(context, rect)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }
}
```

Then use it with `view.backgroundImage`